# Send Mail Using Send Grid with HTML Template

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0, asp.net-core-7.0

I want to send a 4 digit(numeric) OTP using Send Grid With HTML Template in asp.net core7 WebAPI.

I am able to send a mail without template.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to use [FluentEmail](https://github.com/lukencode/FluentEmail). It's an email-sending library that you should be able to add to your .NET Core WebAPI as a [NuGet package](https://github.com/lukencode/FluentEmail#nuget-packages). Their documentation can guide you through.

FluentEmail provides a `Razor renderer` that allows you to create dynamic HTML email templates based on C# models using Razor. FluentEmail also provides native integration with the SendGrid API, or you can use SendGrid through the broader SMTP integration.

[Postal](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Postal.AspNetCore) is a different library that will allow you to do something similar, but it hasn't been updated in a few years.

Answer (score -1):

Hello,
                      
                    
                    
                      
                        Please use the verification code below :
                      
                    
                    
                      
                        {{VERIFICATION_CODE}}
                      
                    
                    
                      
                        If you didn't request this, you can ignore this email or let us know.
                      
                    
                    
                      
                        Thanks! 
My team